# Retrieve value from key in angularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, key-value

I have a json data like this

```
[{
   "ID":699,
   "key":"directorname",
   "value":"SampleValue"}
,{
   "ID":700,
   "key":"template_post_type",
   "value":"Sample2ndValue"}]
```

Now for example I want to retrieve value by "directorname" key.

Is it possible to retrieve value in AngularJS without using repeat syntax?

Note: I want to show value in view (html).

data {"fields": ["directorname", "template_post_type"]}

view structure:

```
    <div ng-repeat="thekey in data.fields">                        
        <span>here for value</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: No, you would require some looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `angular.fromJson` and `Array.prototype.filter` methods:

```
var a = '[{"ID":699,"key":"directorname","value":"SampleValue"},{"ID":700,"key":"template_post_type","value":"Sample2ndValue"}]';
var objArr = angular.fromJson(a).filter(function(item) {
    if (item.key === "directorname") {
        return true;
    }
});
console.log(objArr[0].value);
```

This variant can find all values satisfied condition `key === "directorname"`.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tq75ndm3/6/) example.

Comment: How can I use this in the View?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `arr` variable has the data, there's one way to get the value:

```
var val, i = arr.length;
while (i--) {
  if (arr[i].key === 'directorname') {
    val = arr[i].value;
    break;
  }
}
```

---

Purely angular-ish way, I suppose, would be extracting the required element from `arr` with $filter:

```
var val = $filter('filter')(arr, {key: 'directorname'}, true)[0].value;
```

... but that's, I suppose, too much for such a simple operation.